Distinct and valid parent arrays of a tree
A tree has 10 nodes, numbered from 1 to 10, and its parent array v = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, x, y, z}. How many distinct and valid parent arrays can be formed by giving values to x, y and z?
My (wrong?) approach
10A3 = 10! / 7! = 720
Is this correct or I am missing something?

What is a "parent array"?

That is what it's called in my country and i believe it's also called array representation of a tree

Do I understand correctly? Based on your parent array, we know that $1$ is the root, and that $2$ and $3$ are the children of $1$, and $4$ and $5$ are the children of $2$, and $6$ and $7$ are the children of $3$. $x$ is the parent of $7$, $y$ is the parent of $8$, $z$ is the parent of $9$. The question is to count how many choices for $x,y$ and $z$ describe a valid tree. We do not require the tree to be binary.

@Mike Earnest Yes, that's correct

Well, there was one mistake in my last comment. $x$ is the parent of 8, $y$ is the parent of 9, and $z$ is the parent of 10.

Yes, and I also realise that my answer is wrong because if we calculate the arrangements of nodes 1-10, x, y and z would have themselves as parents which is wrong

Let's break into several cases. First of all, it is possible that $x,y,$ and $z$ are all in $\{1,\dots,7\}$. In this case, $x,y,$ and $z$ can be chosen freely, so there are $7^3$ cases here.
Things get complicated when $8,9,10$ can be children of each other. I think the best way to deal with this is to list out all possible ways these three can be interconnected, and count the number of ways to choose the remaining parents in each case.

There could be a single instance of one of $\{8,9,10\}$ being a child of the other. For example, you need to count arrays like $[0,1,1,2,2,3,3,x,8,z]$, where the parent of $9$ is $8$. There are six ways this could happen; three choices for the parent, and two for the child. Then, there are two remaining parents to assign (in the example, we must assign $x$ and $z$), which both must be in $\{1,\dots,7\}$. In total, we have $6\times 7^2$ ways in this case.

There could be two instances of parenthood among $\{8,9,10\}$. There are two subcases here. There vertices could be connected in a line, like $9 \to 8\to 10$, or with two numbers pointing to the same number, like $10\to 9\gets 8$. There are $3!=6$ possibilities for the line, and $3$ possibilities for the other case, so $9$ ways total. Then, there is a unique remaining parent to assign in the set $\{1,\dots,7\}$. Therefore, we have $9\times 7$ ways here.


Altogether, there are
$$
7^3+6\times 7^2+9\times 7
$$
ways to choose $x,y,$ and $z$.
